# Recover a attribute tag 'selected=true' from a XML group

Tags: xml

I again ask for your help with XML groups and tags. I will appreciate any comments you may offer. Thanks in advance.

So, I have this XML group:

```
<multipleResponseQuestion status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1">
<direction>Pick the correct option(s):</direction>
  <answers>
    <answer correct="true" selected="true">option 1</answer>
    <answer correct="false" selected="false">option 2</answer>
    <answer correct="false" selected="false">option 3</answer>
    <answer correct="false" selected="false">option 4</answer>
  </answers>
</multipleResponseQuestion>
```

and I want to write in a databse the option or options (multiple choice) selected by the user.

I wrote this code:

```
if($answer_group->getName()=="multipleResponseQuestion") { //MULTIPLE RESPONSE QUESTION

$multipleResponseQuestionNumber = 1;

foreach($answer_group->answers->answer as $userMultipleResponseQuestion){

if($status!="notAnswered" && isset($userMultipleResponseQuestion->attributes()->answer)) {
$userAnswer = (string)$userMultipleResponseQuestion->attributes()->selected;
    $values .= "\"" . $userAnswer . "\", ";
    } else {
    $values .= "\"" . $status_notAnswered . "\", ";
}

$columns_create .= $prefix . $questionNumber . "_" . $multipleResponseQuestionNumber . " VARCHAR(50), ";
$columns_insert .= $prefix . $questionNumber . "_" . $multipleResponseQuestionNumber . ", ";

$multipleResponseQuestionNumber++;
}
```

So, I need to recover the "selected=true" options to write them in the database as the $userAnswer. But I can't figure out how to call this attribute. Can someone help, please?

Best
JPMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple after all:

```
if($status != "notAnswered"
  && $userMultipleResponseQuestion->attributes()->selected == 'true')
{
    $userAnswer = (string)$userMultipleResponseQuestion;
}
```